# Record iTunes Connect to publish the app

Tags: iphone, xcode, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I'm trying to push an update of my app on the itunes Connect.

I have created the 1.1 release on the itunes connect. When try to Validate my version in Organizer, it doesn't run.

I expect that I'm wrong with the certificates; how can I check what certificate do I have to put on wich Code Signing submenu (in Xcode)?

Thanks you to help me !

**EDIT:**

I've "ready it for binary submission", and When I want to validate it,

```
The following issues were found during validation :
Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with  an Apple submission certificate.
```

Please help me :-)

**EDIT 2 : Still have the problem:**

[Download the certificate][2]
[Deletete old one and import the new one ][3]
[set the new certificate ... overall][4]
[Get the error again ...][5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this tutorial to make Ad-Hoc Tests : http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action And I dodn't delete the row in the entitlements file (get-task-allow at true).

Now, it's very better, it's xork :D Thanks to all members that give me indications or that tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check your build settings and make sure you have the most recent, valid version of your distribution certificate. It takes a different certificate than the one you may have used with testing.

The distro certificates do not download any sync automatically with Xcode 4 the way the normal testing certificates do. You will probably have to log in and download the distro cert manually.

Comment: Thanks for your asking but I'm confused; I have to re-download the distribution certificate from the Apple Developper Website? I'm using the same certificate than when I published my app... I expect

Comment: It should be the same certificate yes. But if you don't have your build settings pointed to it or validate with with correct certificate, you will see those issues.

Comment: Okay thanks. Can I be wrong if I do that : http://imgpaste.com/9dGr.png ??? (I put all certificates on all profiles)

Comment: That is how I usually do it just to be safe. Then switch them back for testing. I'm sure you could probably edit or create a scheme to prevent this from happening. But for the short term, that should work for you.

Comment: I did it (edit on my post) and I get the same issue, it literally kills me :-/

Comment: give yo my points because you ask me a lot and make me avanced nto my problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is seeking Keychain Access to remove old / duplicate certificates.
If You have multiple ones, Xocde uses the first that it finds (based in some logic in fielssytem, I suppose).
The second suggestion is to control build setting in Xcode.

Comment: OK thanks. I checked it and there could be something wrong : http://imgpaste.com/awXw.png